# Spring Security Google OAuth2 authorizationUri became domain after deployed on aws

Tags: spring, amazon-ec2, spring-security, google-oauth

So I am current testing with spring securtiy with google oauth.
it works fine, when trying to login with google through
/oauth2/authorization/google
on localhost
but when i deployed the application on tomcat on aws ec2 instance,
the authorizationuri became sometime like below

when running on localhost:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?   ............

when running on aws ec2 domain:
**http://{domain}:{port}/o/oauth2/v2/auth? ..........**

but when i manually replace the  http domain and port with https://accounts.google.com/
it directs me to google login page and are able to complete the login successfully.

So i wonder if there is any part of the setting ive being missing or did wrong that cause it to happen.
Thanks in advance.

the complete code for spring security setting is like below

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var oidUserSer:OidUserService


@Bean
fun clientRegistrationRepository(): ClientRegistrationRepository {
    return InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(googleClientRegistration())
}

private fun googleClientRegistration(): ClientRegistration {
    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
        .clientId("clientId")
        .clientSecret("secret")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .redirectUri("https://{domain:port}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
        .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
        .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
        .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
        .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
        .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
        .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
        .clientName("Google")
        .build()
}

@Bean
fun customAuthorizationRequestResolver(): CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver {
    val repo = InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(
        CommonOAuth2Provider.GOOGLE.getBuilder("google")
            .clientName("Google")
            .clientId("61770666483-dj64uabnia7tq2g0kri2ajrb7sl21r3t.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .clientSecret("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")
            .redirectUri("https://{domain:port}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .build()
    )

    val baseUri = OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI
    val customizeAuthorizationRequest= CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(repo,baseUri)


    return customizeAuthorizationRequest
}


/**
 * セキュリティの有効範囲設定
 */
@Override
override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
    // org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException:
    // The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
    // というエラーログがコンソールに出力されるため、下記を追加
    val firewall = DefaultHttpFirewall()
    web.httpFirewall(firewall)
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
        "/img/**",
        "/css/**",
        "/js/**",
        "/libs/**"
    )
}
@Override
@Throws(Exception::class)
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {     


    http.exceptionHandling()

        .authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));


    http.oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/login")                       
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-success", true)   
        .userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(oidUserSer).

        and()
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .authorizationEndpoint()
        .authorizationRequestResolver(customAuthorizationRequestResolver())



  
    http.logout()
        //.logoutRequestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout**"))  
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")     
        .logoutSuccessHandler(CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
        //.invalidateHttpSession(true)
    //セッション設定
    http.sessionManagement().
    invalidSessionUrl("/login?timeout=true")


}
```

}

```
class CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(repo: ClientRegistrationRepository?,
                                     authorizationRequestBaseUri: String?):OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver{
private var defaultResolver:DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver? = DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(repo, authorizationRequestBaseUri)

override fun resolve(request: HttpServletRequest): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? {
    val authorizationRequest:OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? =
        this.defaultResolver?.resolve(request)
    return customAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest)
}


override fun resolve(request: HttpServletRequest?, clientRegistrationId: String?): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? {
    val  authorizationRequest = this.defaultResolver?.resolve(
        request, clientRegistrationId);

    return authorizationRequest?.let { customAuthorizationRequest(it) }
}

private fun customAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest: OAuth2AuthorizationRequest?): OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? {
    var param:OAuth2AuthorizationRequest? = null
    if(authorizationRequest!=null){
        val additionalParameter: LinkedHashMap<String,Any> = LinkedHashMap(authorizationRequest!!.additionalParameters)
        additionalParameter.put("prompt","select_account+consent")
        param = OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest).additionalParameters(additionalParameter).build()
    }
    return param
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? You could try removing your custom request resolver, and only use configuration properties. For example, you can add `?prompt=select_account consent` directly to the end of the `spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.[provider-id].authorization-uri` property. See [Configuring Custom Provider Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-custom-provider-properties).

Comment: Also, is `{domain:port}` in your configs or just an example?

Comment: Yes I am using spring boot and domain port is just an exmaple

Comment: i forgot to mention I used IIS's ARR to reverse proxy to tomcat port, and this occured when i use that setup. But when i setup without IIS  , it works fine as charm

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry, I don’t know much about IIS, but sounds like that’s where the issue is. You may want to include those details in the question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).